# Python, Eclipse addressing my module

Tags: python

I use Eclipse and have problem with addressing my module in Python. I have a package structure:

```
Src
    \Svet
        foo1.py
        \TEST
            \foo2.py (defTest2)
```

I tried to use

```
from Svet.TEST.foo2 import defTest2
```

but I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\....", line 10, in <module>
    import foo2.py
ImportError: No module named defTest2
```

Does anyone have any ideas why I am getting this error?

---

Each Folder contains the .py files which wanted to be used should be Added as resource in PYDEV-PYTHONPATH. 
EVEN IF THEY ARE SUB DIRECTORY OF EACH OTHER

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this has nothing to do with eclipse. is the package path valid? with **init**.py file in the root of the package dir and subdirs? if npot fixing this may solve your problem.

another problem could araise if Svet/TEST/etc folders aren't in the python default search path (like site-packages) if this is the case you could add a .pth file in site-packages with the path to add.

also try if this import works in IDLE Ide then the problem is perhaps eclipse

good luck

Answer (score 0):

The real problem seems to be that you have an **import foo2.py**  somewhere else instead of **import foo2** (if you pasted the full exception traceback -- without putting dots for the path, it'd be easier to actually diagnose it...).